# Where to learn ruby DSL?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, dsl

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define "chefnode" do |chefnode|
    chefnode.vm.box = "geerlingguy/ubuntu1604"
    chefnode.vm.hostname = 'cnode'
    chefnode.vm.network "public_network"
  end

  config.vm.define "chefserver" do |chefserver|
    chefserver.vm.box = "geerlingguy/ubuntu1604"
    chefserver.vm.hostname = 'cserver'
    chefserver.vm.network "public_network"
  end
end
```

I am badly struggling on the above (vagrant dsl) code. Is this Ruby DSL or plain Ruby or something else? Why is there an "=" sign for vm.box and vm.hostname, but not for vm.network??

Comment: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html

Comment: Ruby DSL is plain ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all it's ruby, which as a language can be very handy when you want to create your own DSL. All DSLs are built using base ruby concepts like blocks (`do ... end`) - no magic here.
In your case we may say it's DSL created by Vagrant owners.

Why do they once use `=` and an another time not? In this specific case I assume it's caused by fact you have one argument which is a String and is required, and later on yo may pass a hash with different setup options, like in example from documentation.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
end
```

If they wanted to use `=` they would have to enforce you to pass a Hash in which name key would be required and the rest would be optional, I mean something like this:

```
config.vm.network = { name: "default" }
```

Comment: Thanks! Well, it turns out that to know and code in frameworks like chef, vagrant, once has to have a pretty good understanding of Ruby language and just not rely on the articles like "bare minimum X needed to learn Y", which I think definitely not holds true in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This is standard Ruby, no DSL or metaprogramming magic here.

Ruby is unusual in this regard, but the following are both calling methods on the object returned by `chefserver.vm`:

```
chefserver.vm.hostname = 'chefserver'  # calls method 'hostname='
chefserver.vm.network "public_network" # calls method 'network'
```

Ruby does not require the use of parentheses for a method call (although sometimes they are necessary to clarify to the interpreter what you mean).

I don't know Chef, so I can't say why the `network` call is not `network=`, except that in Ruby calling a method whose name ends with '=' with more than 1 parameter does not work.  And although only 1 parameter to `network` is specified here, in Ruby there can be optional arguments. The method may have been defined something like this:

```
def network(name, something = 'foo')
  # ...
end
```

...so that the method can be called with either 1 or 2 arguments.